# Warmup endpoint not working on App Engine

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, google-app-engine, java-11

I have a kotlin application on App Engine and I'm trying to set up the warmup endpoint with the code bellow:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
class HealthCheck {
    
    @GetMapping
    fun check(): String {
        return "Hey ho, lets go!"
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/_ah/warmup")
    fun warmup() : String {
        return "Warmed up"
    }
}
```

Here is the proof that this endpoint works on localhost:

[image: endpoint works on localhost]

However, when I run `./gradlew clean build` and deploy the jar file to App Engine the endpoint doesn't work

[image]

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F1
entrypoint: java -noverify -jar leaf-bff-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
threadsafe: true

automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 2
  max_instances: 4
  min_idle_instances: 2
  max_concurrent_requests: 25
  target_throughput_utilization: 0.8

inbound_services:
  - warmup
```

I'm targeting the jvm11.

Answer (score 1):

Try by using only `@GetMapping()` to each method

I got it to work like this:

```
@RestController
class HealthCheck {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    fun check(): String {
        return "Hey ho, lets go!"
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/_ah/warmup")
    fun warmup() : String {
        return "Warmed up"
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it unfortunately didnt work

Comment: Are you seeing the same behavior as before or did you get a different behavior?

Comment: unfortunately, the same behavior